# View client side Meteor code

Tags: javascript, security, meteor, client

I understand that client side Meteor code gets loaded into the client's browser - so how can a user actually view the code that gets loaded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Chrome dev tools, you can see the files under sources:

[image]

In Firefox Developer it's under the Debugger tab

Comment: Slightly off topic, but is it particularly "safe" or "best practice" for users to be able to view all the client-side code like this?

Comment: Client side code is always available to the client, it has nothing to do with Meteor. The user's browser executes the javascript so it has to be available to him. Any code you don't want available to the client, surround with if (Meteor.isServer), or put in the server/ directory

Comment: In production client-side code is both minified and uglified. All your files are also concatenated together. It's still readable but barely.